# Phantomjs: Modifying html dom before opening it as webpage

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs

I need to process html files that have corrupted script files that are added to it via  tag.
Im planning to remove all script tag present in the webpage via phantomjs.
But on opening the webpage via webpage.open(), phantomjs parse error is thrown since it cannot parse the JS content within the script tag.
Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
corrupted JS
if(dadadd
 ;
</script>
<body>
some content
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me on suggesting the right way to clean this webpage using phantomjs ?

Answer (score 1):

**It's not (easily) possible.** You could download (not through opening the page, but rather making an Ajax request in `page.evaluate()`) the static html, then change according to your needs, then assign it to `page.content`.

This still might not work, because as soon as you assign it to `page.content`, you're saying that PhantomJS should interpret this source as a page from an unknown domain (about:blank). Since the page source contains all kinds of links/scripts/stylesheets without a domain name, you'll have to change those too in order for the page to successfully load all kinds of resources.

It might be easier to just have a proxy between PhantomJS and the internet with a custom rule to adjust the page source to your needs.